# Java arrays produs of even positions

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So, for example i have an array: `int[] {1,2,3,4,5}`. I need to print the product of even positions, 0 position will be considered even, so it will be: `1 * 3 * 5 = 15`.
When I am summing an array, I am doing something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; sum += arr[i++])
```

and I am receiving the answer correct.

Now, I thought of using the same method for getting the product:

```
int produs = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; produs *= arr[i = i + 2])
```

Here I always get an error. I don't know why, but if I am doing:

```
int produs = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if ( (i & 1) == 0) {
        produs *= arr[i];
    }
}
```

or

```
int produs = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {
  produs *= arr[i];
}
```

I am also getting correct answer.

so, my question is why my method with inline for does not work?

```
int produs = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; produs *= arr[i = i + 2])
```

this one.

Comment: You run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you try to access an element *beyond* the array boundary. That is because the condition `i < arr.length` will **not** be checked when you do `produs *= arr[i = i + 2]` in your "inline method"

Comment: Maybe your loop condition should be `i + 2 < arr.length`. And you need `produs` to be initialized with `1` (but check that you have data first)

Comment: Why would you even use `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; produs *= arr[i = i + 2])` ? It's completely unreadable. Just do the logic inside of a cycle or use a stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you perform a suffix increment operation, the compiler puts the old value on the stack, e.g.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
int i = 0;
int x = arr[i++]; // x will be 0, i is incremented to 1
```

On the other hand, if you would use a prefix increment operation, the compiler puts the new value on the stack, e.g.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
int i = 0;
int x = arr[++i]; // x will be 10, i is incremented to 1
```

Lastly, a variable assignment operation puts the resulting value on the stack, e.g.

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 10, 20, 30 };
int i = 0;
int x = arr[i = i + 3]; // x will be 30, i is increased by 3
```

Therefore, if you use `arr[i = i + 2]` as post-block statement, you actually access the following array elements: `2, 4, 6`, yielding an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I strongly recommended (also for the sake of readability) that you restructure your algorithm to use the `for`-block to do the actual calculation and to use the post-block statement to increase the variable `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) {
    // TODO Calculation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You run into an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because you try to access an element beyond the array boundary. That is because the condition `i < arr.length` will **not** be checked when you do `produs *= arr[i = i + 2]` in the last section of the `for`-loop.

You can just split up your code inside the increment section, in fact you can chain as many statements in there as you wish, you just have to separate them with a comma `,`:

```java
int produs = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; produs *= arr[i], i += 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot implement a for-loop like this inline is that in the incremental part `produs *= arr[i = i + 2]` you will have `i` reaching an index out of the bound of your array because it jumps through 2 steps. Basically in its final iteration, `i` will reach value of 6 which is out of the indices of your array (the final index of your array is 4)  and the part `produs *= arr[i = i + 2]` will produce an error.
In this case, it is better to use the way that worked for you:

```
int produs = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {
  produs *= arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You always instantiate your `produs` with `0`.
If you multiply something with zero, than it will be zero.

You have to instantiate it with `1`, then should your last example work

```
int produsOfEven(int[] array) {

    int produs = 1;

    // step by 2
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
       produs *= array[i];
    }

    return produs;
}
```

### Edit

To your question, why the last example wont work: As already pointed out in the comments, your condition will be checked to "late".

Let us imagine you have the code `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; produs *= arr[i = i + 2])` and array of length 3. Then this steps will be computed:

1. Init `i` with `0`.
2. Check condition `i < arr.length`, it is true.
3. Exec body - no body, nothing will happen.
4. Increase `i` by running `produs *= arr[i = i + 2]`, `i` is now `2`, `produs` is changed by array-index `2`.
5. Check condition `i < arr.length`, it is true.
6. Exec body - no body, nothing will happen.
7. Increase `i` by running `produs *= arr[i = i + 2]`, `i` is now `4`, `produs` is changed by array-index `4`. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` was thrown.

Answer (score -1):

You had better use stream

```
java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger index = new java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger();
int produs = java.util.Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3,4,5})
.filter(i -> index.getAndIncrement() % 2 == 0).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
```